# How can I extract objects using disparity computation on Raspberry Pi with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, object-detection, stereo-3d

The project i'm working on aims to help people with visual disabilities navigate their environment more easily and safely using monochromatic cameras. (stereo vision).
Therefore any function should be as generic as possible.

code in: https://github.com/itamarizen/RaspberryPi4

[flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9xK0.png)

[disparity_SGBM_norm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF88v.png)

My goal is to extract objects as sub-images out of disparity computation.
no need to recognize what exactly the objects are.

Any advices would be appreciated.

I've try so many things and algorithm including histogram analysis but didn't succeed to get clearly the chair, person and the bin from those stere image.

```
def extract_closest_objects(disparity, display=True):
    # Apply Gaussian blur to the disparity image
    sigma = 20
    blurred = filters.gaussian(disparity, sigma=sigma)
    blurred = cv2.medianBlur(disparity, 25, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    # Compute the x and y derivatives using the Sobel filter
    sobel_x = filters.sobel_v(blurred)
    sobel_y = filters.sobel_h(blurred)
    
    # Compute the magnitude of the gradient
    sobel_mag = np.sqrt(sobel_x ** 2 + sobel_y ** 2)
    
    # Threshold the magnitude to create a binary image
    threshold = filters.threshold_otsu(sobel_mag)
    binary = sobel_mag > threshold

    # Compute the minimum size of objects and holes based on the size of the image
    min_object_size = int((disparity.shape[0] * disparity.shape[1]) * 0.00005)  # % of image size
    min_hole_size = int((disparity.shape[0] * disparity.shape[1]) * 0.00005) 
    binary = morphology.remove_small_objects(binary, min_object_size)
    binary = morphology.remove_small_holes(binary, min_hole_size)
    
    # Label the connected components in the filled image
    labels = label(binary)
    fig = px.imshow(disparity, binary_string=True)
    fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='skip') # hover is only for label info

    # Extract the region properties of the labeled components
    props = regionprops(labels,disparity)
    properties = ['area', 'eccentricity', 'perimeter', 'intensity_mean']

    # For each label, add a filled scatter trace for its contour,
    # and display the properties of the label in the hover of this trace.
    for index in range(1, labels.max()):
        label_i = props[index].label
        contour = measure.find_contours(labels == label_i, 0.5)[0]
        y, x = contour.T
        hoverinfo = ''
        for prop_name in properties:
            hoverinfo += f'<b>{prop_name}: {getattr(props[index], prop_name):.2f}</b><br>'
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=x, y=y, name=label_i,
            mode='lines', fill='toself', showlegend=False,
            hovertemplate=hoverinfo, hoveron='points+fills'))

    plotly.io.show(fig)`
```

or:

```
def extract_closest_objects(disparity, display=False):
    # Compute the histogram of the disparity values
    histogram, bins = np.histogram(disparity, bins=256,density=True)
    
    # remove total black (backgraund)
    histogram[0] = 0
    '''
    distance: This parameter controls the minimum horizontal distance between peaks. A larger value will result in fewer peaks being detected, while a smaller value will detect more peaks. A good starting point could be to set distance to a fraction of the total number of bins in the histogram, such as distance = len(bins) // 20.

    prominence: This parameter controls the minimum height difference between a peak and its surrounding valleys. A larger value will result in fewer peaks being detected, while a smaller value will detect more peaks. A good starting point could be to set prominence to a fraction of the maximum histogram value, such as prominence = histogram.max() // 10.

    width: This parameter controls the minimum horizontal width of a peak. A larger value will result in wider peaks being detected, while a smaller value will detect narrower peaks. A good starting point could be to set width to a fraction of the total number of bins in the histogram, such as width = len(bins) // 50.

    height: This parameter controls the minimum height of a peak. A larger value will result in taller peaks being detected, while a smaller value will detect shorter peaks. A good starting point could be to set height to a fraction of the maximum histogram value, such as height = histogram.max() // 20.

    threshold: This parameter controls the minimum absolute height of a peak. A larger value will result in fewer peaks being detected, while a smaller value will detect more peaks. A good starting point could be to set threshold to a fraction of the maximum histogram value, such as threshold = histogram.max() // 50.
    '''
    if not isinstance(disparity, np.ndarray):
        raise TypeError("Input must be a NumPy array.")
        
    # Compute the histogram of the disparity values
    hist, bins = np.histogram(disparity, bins=256, density=True)
    
    # Remove total black (background)
    hist[0] = 0
    
    # Determine peak locations in the histogram
    peak_kwargs = {
        'plateau_size': 1,
        'height': np.max(hist) * 0.2,
        'threshold': None,
        'distance': 5,
        'prominence': np.max(hist) * 0.05,
        'width': None
    }
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(hist, **peak_kwargs)
    
    if len(peaks) == 0:
        raise ValueError("No peaks found in histogram.")
    
    if display:
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
        plt.plot(histogram);plt.title("histogram")
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
        plt.plot(peaks, histogram[peaks], "xr");plt.plot(histogram); plt.legend(['peaks']);plt.title("analyzed histogram")
        plt.axhline(peak_kwargs['height'], linestyle="--", color="gray")
        # Plot vertical lines at the midpoint between adjacent peaks
        colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange', 'yellow', 'pink', 'brown', 'gray', 'teal']
        for i in range(len(peaks)):
            color = colors[i % len(colors)]
            plt.axvline(peaks[i] - peak_kwargs['distance'], linestyle="--", color=color)
            plt.axvline(peaks[i] + peak_kwargs['distance'], linestyle="--", color=color)
        plt.suptitle("Histogram analysis")
        plt.show(block=False)


    # Use regionprops to extract the objects corresponding to each peak in the histogram
    objects = []
    for i in range(len(peaks)):
        # Define the minimum and maximum disparity values for the current object
        min_val, max_val = peaks[-1-i] - distance, peaks[-1-i] + distance

        # Extract the current object using thresholding and connected component analysis
        obj = cv2.normalize(disparity, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
        obj[(disparity < min_val) | (disparity > max_val)] = 0
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(obj, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        labels = label(thresh.astype(np.uint8))
        num_labels = np.max(labels)

        # Extract the regions corresponding to the current object
        for j in range(1, num_labels+1):
            mask = (labels == j).astype(np.uint8)
            props = regionprops(mask, intensity_image=obj)
            if len(props) == 0:
                continue
            # Choose the region with the highest mean intensity as the object
            max_mean_intensity_region = max(props, key=lambda x: x.mean_intensity)
            mask = max_mean_intensity_region.filled_image
            objects.append(mask)
                
        # Display the segmented object
        if display:
            plt.figure()
            plt.imshow(obj, cmap='gray')
            plt.title(f'Object {i+1}')
            plt.show(block=False)

    return objects
```